# How to find intermediate nodes between two nodes using Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

[image: Department with Users]We have tree of Departments as shown in the picture

I need to list all department nodes and associated users for node **between** node D1 and D1.A1.B1

I need a Cypher query for this.

Result should be department: *D1, D1.A1, D1.A1.B1* and users: U1,U2,U4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following Cypher query using a [variable-length pattern matching](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/patterns/#cypher-pattern-varlength), nodes(), `unwind` and `collect()` should work. Explanation on comments:

```
// match the entire path from 'D1' to 'D1.A1.B1'
match p = ( {name : 'D1'} )-[*]->( {name : 'D1.A1.B1'} )
// get all nodes (departments) from path
with nodes(p) as deps
// unwind deps collection to individual departments
unwind deps as dep
// match workers and managers directly connected to dep nodes
match (dep)<-[:WORKER|:MANAGER]-(u:User)
return collect(dep) as departments, collect(u) as users
```

Comment: One more query, There are users associated with each department nodes with ROLE relationship, how can find out list of users between intermediate nodes D1 and D1.A1.B1

Comment: @Yogi Sorry, I do not understand your question about ROLE relationship. Can you provide some more details?

Comment: I have updated my question along with picture...pls check

Comment: @Yogi, try this: `match p = ( {name : 'D1'} )-[*]->( {name : 'D1.A1.B1'} )
with nodes(p) as deps
unwind deps as dep
match (dep)<-[:WORKER|:MANAGER]-(u:User)
return collect(dep) as departments, collect(u) as users`